# How to truncate git history and keep working with recent branches?

Tags: git

I tried several solutions proposed on StackOverflow, but none actually worked. Eventhough, the case is not so complicated, but I could not find the right answer.

After 1 year of development, our application now counts around 2000 commits. In the early ages, it was a bit experimental, and some URLs and credentials have been stored in configuration files and committed into git. These elements are encrypted now, but this history still raises alerts from the Intrusion Detection System when pushed into the production environment!

The solution I see is to truncate history to the last version released on validation environment, which would remove old configuration files content. As we have 2 running branches and a fork, the result of a truncation should allow pull-request and merging. I tried the following:

```
git checkout --orphan temp 429200bb80810c8d87efd8a598a0c18a9672ec6f
git commit -m "Truncate history"
git rebase --onto temp 429200bb80810c8d87efd8a598a0c18a9672ec6f master
```

But it does not keep any of the commits ids, and all merge attempts result in an error message:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

How can I actually truncate git history and keep working with recent branches?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The hash ID of any given commit incorporates the hash IDs of *all historical commits*, so any time you truncate history, you get an all-new repository with all-new hash IDs. Other than that ("other than that, Mrs Lincoln, how was the play") it's pretty simple, but it's probably better to use filter-repo or filter-branch after using `git replace` to wipe away some history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just rebase the recent branches on top of the newer ones, even if they are disconnected. It's a little bit nagging but it's not too difficult.... as an example, suppose that you have branches `featureA` `featureB` and `featureC` that started being developed on top of `develop`

So, you rewrote the history of `develop` and so now you have `develop` pointing to the *new* develop.... but you were careful enough to keep an `old_develop` branch (or at least a revision ID) that points to the original branch position, right?

Well, rewriting the feature branches to be on the new develop is as simple as running:

```
for i in featureA featureB featureC; do
    git rebase --onto develop old_develop $i
do
```

That is, assuming that the branches are straight lines from develop. If they are *not* straight lines, then you need to play with other options of rebase like `--rebase-merges`.